# how can I get this kind of box shadow or outline?

Tags: css

Is this a box shadow or an outline? I'm confused because outlines can't have radius property and box shadows have blur effect.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be a combination of `border` and `box-shadow` and `outline: none`.

I have added the `border` and `box-shadow` to default state, if needed we can move that to `:focus`

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  zoom: 250%;
}

.custom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #0000ff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt rgb(0 0 255 / 30%);
}

.custom:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="custom">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an outline with a rgba color on an input with a border radius:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #ae11fc;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

input:focus {
  outline: #ae11fc44 solid 0.2rem;
}
```

Checkout out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y4sro9f/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required styling by adding the following properties to your input style. You can play around it here: https://codepen.io/taleyamirza/pen/ExmzYJr

```
input:focus { 
  outline-color: #6c8afc;
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #6c8afc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #6c8afc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #6c8afc;
}
```